# Laravel 5 - redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm not able to redirect in my application using:

```
return redirect('/);
```

The problem comes from when the user do a login using facebook.
Facebook returns a url that contains #*=* and seems to block my site execution:

```
public function createUserFromFacebookInfos( $info )
    {
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'email' => $info->email
        ]);

        $user->name = $info->name;
        $user->provider_token = $info->token;
        $user->provider_id = 1;
        $user->save();

        $this->auth->login( $user );

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

How can I remove that piece of url?
I have read that that code is added when `redirect_uri` is missing, but where should I set this `redirect_uri`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication).

Comment: Is createUserFromFacebookInfos your controller route or it is sub-function? If you return redirect from sub-function then you need to propagate it further. adding # to the URL does not matter, it does not even reach the server and is only JS domain

Comment: @smartman thanks, it is a sub-function! Added the return redirect in the main function and it worked!

Comment: I added it as a answer also so you can accept and close the question

Comment: What do you mean with propagate further? I'm stuck on the same issue, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are propagating the redirect object returned from sub-function out from your main controller function.

Comment: Can you give an example please? I'm stuck on the same problem